# Find a file in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have already done `docker-compose up -d` to create several containers and it is running.

The configuration files are listed below. `Docker Root Dir:` is `/var/lib/docker`.

I would like to know how to find `/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf` in the disk, so that I could check the content (e.g., whether it is the right version).

Does anyone know?

`Dockerfile.nginx`:

```
FROM bitnami/nginx:1.16
COPY ./funfun.io /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf
COPY ./ssl/MyCompanyLocalhost.cer /opt/MyCompanyLocalhost.cer
COPY ./ssl/MyCompanyLocalhost.pvk /opt/MyCompanyLocalhost.pvk
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  funfun-node:
    image: funfun
    restart: always
    build: .
    environment:
    - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/news
    env_file:
    - ./.env
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  funfun-nginx:
    image: funfun-nginx
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx

    ports:
    - "80:8081"
    - "443:8443"
    depends_on:
    - funfun-node
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.4
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - "10studio-mongo:/data/db"
    ports:
    - "27018:27017"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 10studio
volumes:
  10studio-mongo:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd specify `container_name: funfun-nginx-container` in your compose file for the nginx service, then you can do:
`docker exec -it funfun-nginx-container bash` to enter the container and search for the file like you would normally. You can also check without entering the container using `docker exec funfun-nginx-container cat /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf` (if you gave it that name)

Comment: It works... Additionally, I could also check the (default) name of the container by `docker container ls`.

Comment: You can also `docker-compose exec funfun-nginx` and it will go to the right place.  You shouldn't usually need to specify `container_name:`.